# Are "updateable views" the correct approach for manually editing multiple tables

Tags: postgresql, view

I have a PostgreSQL database with the following tables

```
person
city
country
```

Each person is linked to a city through a `city_id` foreign key, and each city is linked to a country through `country_id` in a similar way.

To easily view the names of each person's city and country, I create a view:

```
CREATE VIEW person_view AS
  SELECT
    person.id, 
    person.name,
    city.name as city,
    country.name as country
  FROM person
  LEFT JOIN city ON person.city_id = city.id
  LEFT JOIN country ON city.country_id  = country.id
```

Which gives something easy to read.

```
| id | name   | city     | country       |
------------------------------------------
| 1  | Steve  | New York | United States |
| 2  | Rachel | Paris    | France        |
```

Now, using a program like dbeaver, I was hoping to manage these entries using this view. Instead of looking up IDs whenever a person's city/country needs to change, it'd be much easier just to type in changes in the view and have those changes carry over to the original tables.

I thought that this was what an updatable view was meant for, but dbeaver will not allow this view to be updated directly, and suggests implementing `INSTEAD OF UPDATE` triggers or `ON UPDATE DO INSTEAD` rules.

Am I approaching this correctly? Is the operation I've described here what updatable views are meant to do?

Comment: It is Postgres not dbeaver that is  preventing the update on this view. It is **not an updateable** view. Updateable views cannot have Join and other restrictions. (see [Updatable Views](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createview.html)). So you are not approaching this correctly.

Comment: DBeaver's suggestion is correct. A view that uses joins can only be bade updateable if you implement an INSTEAD OF trigger

Comment: @Belayer thanks, do you have any suggestions on how this could be approached?

Comment: You implement an `Instead of` trigger. The trigger determines which columns and from there which tables must be updated and does so as appropriate.  This may involve a single column update or multiple columns in multiple tables.  (For the data supplied looks like only `persons` table needs updating, but it is possible that all 3 need updating. Only you can decide that.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/y1cedRJV)
Only show update trigger. You can do similar thing for insert and delete.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION person_view_upd_trig_fn ()
    RETURNS TRIGGER
    AS $$
BEGIN
    IF tg_op = 'UPDATE' THEN
        IF NEW.name <> OLD.name THEN
            RAISE NOTICE 'update person name';
            UPDATE
                person
            SET
                name = NEW.name
            WHERE
                id = OLD.id;
            RETURN new;
        END IF;
        IF NEW.city <> OLD.city AND NEW.country = OLD.country THEN
            RAISE NOTICE 'update city name';
            IF (
                SELECT
                    count(DISTINCT country_id)
                FROM
                    city
                WHERE
                    name = OLD.city OR name = NEW.city) = 2 THEN
                RAISE EXCEPTION 'not good';
            END IF;
            IF (
                SELECT
                    city_id
                FROM
                    city
                WHERE
                    name = NEW.city) IS NULL THEN
                RAISE EXCEPTION 'city not in the list';
            END IF;
            UPDATE
                person
            SET
                city_id = (
                    SELECT
                        city_id
                    FROM
                        city
                    WHERE
                        name = NEW.city)
            WHERE
                id = OLD.id;
            RETURN new;
        END IF;
        IF NEW.country <> OLD.country AND NEW.city <> OLD.city THEN
            RAISE NOTICE 'updating person country & city';
            IF NOT EXISTS (
                SELECT
                FROM
                    country
                WHERE
                    name = NEW.country) THEN
            RAISE EXCEPTION 'not good';
        END IF;
        UPDATE
            person
        SET
            city_id = (
                SELECT
                    city_id
                FROM
                    city
                WHERE
                    name = NEW.city)
        WHERE
            id = OLD.id;
        RETURN new;
    END IF;
    RAISE NOTICE 'new.person_view:%', new;
    RAISE NOTICE 'old.person_view:%', old;
    RETURN NULL;
END IF;
END
$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

create trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER person_view_upd_trig
    INSTEAD OF  UPDATE  ON person_view
    FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE person_view_upd_trig_fn();
```

person_view id column cannot update, update will have no effect. all other 3 column can update.

---

`IF tg_op = 'UPDATE' THEN` is not that redundant. You can add more control block, like `IF tg_op = 'DELETE THEN` in this function. Then one function, you can control 3 actions/trigger(delete, update, insert), instead of 3 function and 3 triggers.

---

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-trigger.html

> A trigger function **must** return either NULL or a record/row value
> having exactly the structure of the table the trigger was fired for.

and

> INSTEAD OF triggers (which are always row-level triggers, and may only
> be used on views) can return null to signal that they did not perform
> any updates, and that the rest of the operation for this row should be
> skipped (i.e., subsequent triggers are not fired, and the row is not
> counted in the rows-affected status for the surrounding
> INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE). Otherwise a nonnull value should be returned,
> to signal that the trigger performed the requested operation. For
> INSERT and UPDATE operations, the return value should be **NEW**, which
> the trigger function may modify to support INSERT RETURNING and UPDATE
> RETURNING (this will also affect the row value passed to any
> subsequent triggers, or passed to a special EXCLUDED alias reference
> within an INSERT statement with an ON CONFLICT DO UPDATE clause). For
> DELETE operations, the return value should be OLD.

Comment: Brilliant. This is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks for providing the fiddle demo.

Comment: Can you give me any insight on what these functions are meant to return? I see that it is executing `UPDATE` on the `person` table, which is which is the expected behaviour. What is the difference between returning `new` and `NULL`, though? What does it do with `new`?

Comment: Second question: is the `tg_op = 'UPDATE'` redundant given that, when creating the trigger, we're specifying `INSTEAD OF  UPDATE  ON person_view`

Comment: @AndrewPlowright I update the question. Hope it will answer your question.